# Legal reasons not use Home Basic / Home Premium in a business

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

Is there any legal reason why you can't use the Home versions of Windows 7 or Vista in a business environment?

The technical differences and limitations are well documented online but I can't find anything that says there is a legal restriction like there is for the Home editions of Microsoft Office.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

None whatsoever.